# .htaccess rewrite domain and subdomain to directory and subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to use my .htaccess file to point domains/subdomains to directories/subdirectories without changing the url in the browser.

Examples of the incoming url and the directory it should point to:

- domain1.com/* -> /domain1.com/www/*
- foo.domain1.com/* -> /domain1.com/foo/*
- bar.domain1.com/* -> /domain1.com/bar/*
- domain2.com/* -> /domain2.com/www/*
- foo.domain2.com/* -> /domain2.com/foo/*
- bar.domain2.com/* -> /domain2.com/bar/*

Here's my current attempt that is continually appending the directory/subdirectory to the url:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:([^.]+)\.)?([^.]+)\.([^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%2\.%3/%1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%2.%3/%1/$1 [L,NE,P,QSA,R]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a little work, but that to the help of the first response, I was able to get everything working eventually.

Here's my final solution to this issue:

```
## Turn the rewrite engine on to allow for url mapping to work
RewriteEngine on

## Don't require a trailing "/" for directories
DirectorySlash Off

## If subdomain was missing, redirect into the "www" subdirectory

# If no %{REQUEST_FILENAME} was provided, redirect to the "www" subdirectory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /%2.%3/www/ [END,NC]

# If a %{REQUEST_FILENAME} was provided, redirect to the directory/file in the "www" subdirectory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%2.%3/www/$1 [END,NC,QSA]

# If subdomain was given, redirect into the given subdirectory

# If no %{REQUEST_FILENAME} was provided, redirect to the given subdirectory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /%2.%3/%1/ [END,NC]

# If a %{REQUEST_FILENAME} was provided, redirect to the directory/file in the given subdirectory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%2.%3/%1/$1 [END,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated? The following should satisfy all requirements you listed:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^ /www%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Have a try yourself at [made with love](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=e46a0502-e742-4f78-acd6-3e602308ec4a)

Comment: thanks for the input!

I tried your example, and still ran into some problems including missing trailing slashes on directories, directories not automatically going to index pages, endless loops, and some others.

But thanks to your advice, I was able to sort it out, and will post my final product in another answer.

Comment: Sure, other settings may always interfere, answers here are not meant to be copied 1:1. Great you found a working solution!